# Scalar and Table-Valued Functions for CRM Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crm, user-defined-functions

I have reports that are ran from a Microsoft CRM website. The values that are needed for the report have previously been calculated with JavaScript and saved to SQL. Those calculations have proved to be unreliable and often incorrect. So there is a shift into performing those calculations needed for the reports on SQL Server rather than in the JS.

Currently, several scalar functions have been created to perform these calculations with an x amount of parameters needed to calculate the value. The first problem is those functions may need parameters that need to be used by an additional function inside the base function. Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SomeCalculation
    (@FuncParam1 int, 
     @FuncParam2 int,
     @OtherFuncParam1 int,
     @OtherFuncParam2 int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OtherFuncValue int;
    SET @OtherFuncValue = OtherFunc(@OtherFuncParam1, @OtherFuncParam2);

    RETURN (@FuncParam1 * @FuncParam2) / @OtherFuncValue;
END
```

The problem with this is that several of the functions need many parameters (as many as 30+) to perform its calculation plus the needed calculations of all the other needed functions. The maintainability of 30+ parameters is HIGHLY undesirable.

A solution I have thought of is to create the scalar functions with params only needed for any joins and `Table-Valued Functions` that handle returning the appropriate values needed for the function. A rough example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SomeCalculation(@SomeIdToJoin)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SomeCalculationColumns(@SomeIdToJoin) AS NewParams;

    DECLARE @OtherFuncValue int;
    SET @OtherFuncValue = OtherFunc(NewParams.OtherFuncParam1, NewParams.OtherFuncParam2);

    RETURN (NewParams.FuncParam1 * NewParams.FuncParam2) / @OtherFuncValue;
END
```

I think that solution cleans up the parameters needed but does not quite solve the maintainability problem. I am also worried about performance with this solution.

I am open to any suggestions to improve this approach or to any additional approaches that would make these calculations easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: move your calculation to be server-side (plugins) instead of JS

Comment: Can you provide an example or resource on how to use that approach?

Comment: it depends on what is your code doing. Let's say for example that you have a field inside account entity that is the sum of the amounts of all the orders made. with a plugin you find the relevant trigger (in this case when the order is closed) to update the value inside account, so your report will just fetch the value. you can start from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx

Comment: An issue I have with the plugins vs SQL is that the user will still be responsible for performing the actions to make the calculations fire. I also have issues with updating those functions and perform automated tests to verify correctness. The goal here is to make the report generation fire off the calculations and allow those calculations to be fired/reused across multiple reports.

Comment: and you can't store the calculations with SQL. Updating directly the CRM DB is not supported.

Comment: I agree with Guido.  Doing calculations in javascript is inherently unreliable while plugin logic is both reliable and easily unit tested.  If performance is an issue and you only want the calculations to occur before the report is run you could have the plugin logic trigger when records reach a certain status or a button is pressed.  For instance you could have a "View Report" button triggering a plugin to perform the calculations and then launch a report on that info.